# Laravel 5.3 show images in the view

Tags: laravel

I am having trouble showing images. I have stored images in:

```
nameproject/storage/images/2017/sep/
```

and I have created a link from the public folder:

```
ln -s storage/images public/images
```

and in my view:

```
<td><img src="{{ asset($post->image )}}" height="42" width="42"/></td>
```

but I receive the error:

```
GET https://challenge.local/images/2017/Sep/1504974522.jpeg 404 ()
```

Comment: `asset()` function points to public directory, doesn't it?

Comment: I don't know . . .

Comment: As @Yachi웃 mentioned on the first comment `assets()` function points to the public directory, If you want to store your files or images on storage dir, Please read the "File Storage" section on documentation. You have to store your files inside the `storage/app" dir and create a symlink to that dir from the public folder. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#configuration

Comment: that's what I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this..images folder in public folder..

`{{ URL::to('/images/2017/Sep/'.$post->image) }}
http://localhost/laraveltest/public/images/2017/Sep/1504974522.jpeg`